# Как передать доп параметр в колбек функцию?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function foo(locationresult){};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foo,foo); //вызывает foo с параметром locationresult
```

Вопрос - можно как-то передать в foo что-то своё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback` вызывается внутри функции, соответственно набор параметров также определяется внутри и к нему нет доступа.

Для передачи дополнительной информации можно использовать

1. замыкания

   ```
   var variable = ...;
   function foo(locationresult){
       variable // доступ к внешней переменной
   };
   ```
2. использовать [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

   ```
   var fooBinded = foo.bind(context, arg1,arg2, ...)
   ```

   в этом случае будет проблема если функция использует `this`, и вызывающая функция пытается ее задать.
   определение функции должно поменяться на следующее

   ```
   function foo(arg1, arg2, ..., locationresult){
   ```